# How to troubleshoot and resolve a particular display error in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a display issue that seem to occur only with Google Chrome and only on my computer.  I would like to resolve it.  The issue is:

- [This site](https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/fr/) is in French, and contains several occurrences of the letter à.  On *some* of those occurrences, the space after the letter is missing ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajdbb.jpg)).

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- I have tried incognito mode in Chrome, and the issue is still present.
- I have tried a different browser (Internet Explorer and Firefox), and the issue is not present.
- I have tried Google Chrome on a different computer (Win 10, x86) and the issue is not present.
- I have uninstalled Google Chrome via control panel-->add/remove programs, re-downloaded it, and re-installed it, but the issue is still present.

I am running Google Chrome version 65.0.3325.146, and Win 10, x64.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, in this case, was because I had the same font (Questrial) installed locally.  When I uninstalled that font, the issue went away (see [outside thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/89ompq/google_chrome_displays_errors_but_only_on_my/)).  I'm still not sure exactly *why* having the same font installed locally caused the issue, since I certainly have other web fonts installed locally without issue.  Plus, I installed this font locally for a reason, because I need it in a local application (Photoshop/Illustrator).  Not sure how I'll get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your fonts in unicode settings:

Click on 3 points --> Settings --> in search settings write unicode.

[image]

Comment: @F.Rahamin OK I checked the settings. But what exactly am I looking for?  I checked the Unicode settings on both my desktop computer (the computer with the issue) and my laptop (a computer without the issue), and they have identical settings.

Comment: Check if all fonts are the same if all right try to use this chrome extension and set Unicode UTF-8  

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-character-encoding/bpojelgakakmcfmjfilgdlmhefphglae

Please let me know

Comment: I checked if all fonts were identical between both computers, and they were.  I then installed the extension you suggested.  Unicode was already set to 'UTF-8.'  However there was no change in the issue--it was still present.